# Bash update file modified date

Tags: file, shell, date, timestamp

I would like to make a shell script that updates the modified date on a directory and files. This is because I have realised that when you download a file it has the date from when it was uploaded. For example when I downloaded the cvim plugin for vim the date was `15 Dec 2008`. I would like a script that will change that date to the current time.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use

```
touch file
```

to update the last modified time stamp. If your downloader can write to stdout this is even simpler:

```
downloader http://someURL > file
```

because a newly created (or replaced) `file` has always the current time as the last modified time.

For directories, you can create and remove a dummy file to update its last modified time stamp:

```
touch dummy; rm dummy
```

But everyone else on this planet doesn't care for directory timestamps. Why do you? :-)

Comment: I dont mind. I just wanted to know how. It is also useful if I am installing plugins all the time and one of them breaks my application then I know what the latest plugin was when I installed it.

Comment: @aPyDeveloper Okay. Interesting trivia: you can use touch to update with a time stamp you specify: `touch -d YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:SS file`.

Comment: Thanks. Also the main reason was because I just wanted to know how to.

Comment: @aPyDeveloper "Questions are the beginning to wisdom" -- Lt. Worf

Comment: And knowing the answers is full wisdom! Lol